# R read file with curly braces

Tags: r, readfile

I have a following txt file:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3
1 5 {Joe, John, Sam}
2 9 {Mike}
3 5 {Bob, Alice}
```

I am trying to read it with following command, but it gives an error:

```
data = read.table("file_location/data.txt", sep=" ", strip.white=TRUE, header=TRUE)

more columns than column names
```

How can I read such file?

Comment: do you have to do this in r? replace the braces with quotes (using your fav text editor or shell command) and read it in normally

Comment: Yes, in R. And I do not want to start replacing characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy:

```
> read.table(text = chartr("{}", "''", readLines("data.txt")), header = TRUE)
  Header1 Header2        Header3
1       1       5 Joe, John, Sam
2       2       9           Mike
3       3       5     Bob, Alice
```

The key part is using `chartr` to replace curly brackets with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it without replacing characters.  `read.pattern` extracts the capture groups (the text matching the parenthesized portions of the regular expression) and arranges them into a data.frame.  We read the header in separately.  The `text = Lines` part could be replaced with `"myfile"`, say, to read the text from a file.

```
# test data
Lines <- "Header1 Header2 Header3
1 5 {Joe, John, Sam}
2 9 {Mike}
3 5 {Bob, Alice}"

library(gsubfn)

DF <- read.pattern(text = Lines, pattern = "^ *(\\S+) (\\S+) (.*)", skip = 1, 
   as.is = TRUE, col.names = read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE, nrow = 1))
```

giving:

```
 Header1 Header2          Header3
1       1       5 {Joe, John, Sam}
2       2       9           {Mike}
3       3       5     {Bob, Alice}
```

A visualization of the regular expression is shown here:

```
^ *(\S+) (\S+) (.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0_ID7H57OacPD42Y)